# A difficulty in understanding the n-dimensional second order derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The example and its solution is given below:

> [image]
>
> [image]

But I do not understand why in the calculation of $D^2 f(2,3)(u)^2$ the $u^2$ takes this form ....$ u_1^2 + u_{1}u_{2} + u_{2}^2$ from where the term $u_{1}u_{2}$ comes?...... could anyone explain this for me please?

**Edit:**
I remember that my professor said that the dot product in two dimensional is just the square of the term but I do not understand this statement..... but I do not understand this statement.

Comment: What is this from??

Comment: $ u_1^2 + u_{1}u_{2} + u_{2}^2$ @Randall  from where the term $u_{1}u_{2}$ comes?

Comment: No, the book/notes.

Comment: Petrovic "Advanced calculus theory and practice" @Randall

Comment: I remember that my professor said that the dot product in two dimensional is just the square of the term but I do not understand this statement.@Randall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object $q:=D^2f(2,3)$ is a quadratic form in the increment variable ${\bf u}=(u_1,u_2)$. The vector ${\bf u}$ is  attached at the point ${\bf p}=(2,3)\in{\rm dom}(f)$, in other words: ${\bf u}$ is a vector in the tangent space $T_{\bf p}$. One has
$$q({\bf u})=\sum_{i, \>k=1}^2 f_{.ik}({\bf p})\>u_iu_k=[u_1 \ u_2]\left[\matrix{-6&6\cr 6&30\cr}\right]\left[\matrix{u_1\cr u_2\cr}\right]=-6u_1^2+12u_1u_2+30 u_2^2\ .$$

Comment: what is $T_{p}$?